# ILNumerics Code generation: HYCALPER

Tags: ilnumerics

I just downloaded ILNumerics source code and was wondering what Hycalper is.
I've spotted it in code like this:

```
#region HYCALPER AUTO GENERATED CODE
...
#endregion HYCALPER AUTO GENERATED CODE
```

It seems to be some sort of code generator, but I had never heard of it before. I wonder if it is part of the GPL / commercial ILNumerics, or is it an external tool. Where could I find it so that I examine what it is capable of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the function overloads in ILNumerics are auto-generated by Hycalper. Most the time (if not always?) functions are only defined as "double" overload and replicated for all other input element types. This significantly eases bugfixing. Also, many functions are automatically derived from a single template function (e.g. sin) by replacing the few differences (e.g. cos).

However, we stripped off the Hycalper definition tags prior to publishing the GPL Community Edition. The main reason is to keep the code clean, simple and independent from other tools besides a C# compiler. The Hycalper tool - as useful as it is - does not provide that. The region tags you see were just left over from the last Hycalper run. They distinguish the auto parts from the 'template' parts. If you are after modifying the code, you may silently ignore them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, but could you elaborate a bit on what exactly Hycalper is. Is-it part of (non-opened sourced) ILNumerics? Is-it third party? I could not find anything about it by just googling, this is why it interrogates me.